# Why my scrollView is nil?

Tags: xcode, swift, view, viewcontroller, fatal-error

How can be possible that the scrollview is nil when using the first:`@IBAction afegeixGrafic` but when using `@IBAction func button` it isn't'?
I got the class `GraficsBalancGlobalViewController` which is subclass of the class `GraficViewController`

```
class GraficsBalancGlobalViewController: GraficViewController {
  @IBAction func afegeixGrafic(sender: NSButton) {
    addNewGrafic() // which is set on the GraficViewController
  }
}
```

And when I perform the `IBAction` `afegeixGrafic` my program crashes on the line marked below:

```
class GraficViewController: NSViewController, GraficViewDataSource {
  @IBAction func button(sender: NSButton) {
    addNewGrafic()
  }

  func addNewGrafic() {
    let frame = NSRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width , height: self.view.bounds.width * 0.25)
    let nouGrafic = GraficView(frame: frame)
    scrollView.addSubview(nouGrafic) <---- BREAK here!
  }

  @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSView!
  //...more code
}
```

The compiler says that:

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

but the button (IBAction) inside the `GraficViewController` works well!! So i suppose that the problem is related with the scrollView, but I have no idea of what can be.. It is initialized..

I try this too:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSView? {
  didSet {
    guard let sview = scrollView else {
      addNewGrafic()
      return // because scrollView is nil for some reason, but don't work
    }
  }
}
```

[image: The call stack]

[image]

Full code:

```
class GraficsBalancGlobalViewController: GraficViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do view setup here.
}

@IBAction func afegeixGrafic(sender: NSButton) {
    //performSegueWithIdentifier("Nou Grafic", sender: nil)
    //let viewController = storyboard!.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier(identifier!) as! GraficsBalancGlobalViewController
    addNewGrafic()

}

@IBAction func eliminaGrafic(sender: NSButton) {
}

}
```

[image]

Comment: `scrollView` will always be nil in your last code block -- that's what the guard is checking for -- and it drops into the else only when it's nil

Comment: yes, sorry that can be confusing. Don't care about the last code part, the important is the first one.

Comment: Show us the call stack at the point of the error.

Comment: @LouFranco It works well when using the `IBAction button`, but then using the `IBAction afegeixGrafic`happens the the thing that i'm going to add on my question!

Comment: There is not enough information here to help you.  The most likely reason it's nil is because of when it's being called -- we can see that in the call stack.

Comment: That screenshot doesn't include the call stack.

Comment: It works when the button that calls the `addNewGrafic()`,  the view appear. But when i use a different button called `afegeixGrafic` which is in a different viewController which is a subclass of the viewcontroller that have the scrollview on it just appears to be nil the scrollview

Answer (score 2):

Its nil because of how you instantiated GraficsBalancGlobalViewController. You set it up with a xib or a storyboard however you instantiated it without one. 
Do this:

```
 let viewController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as GraficsBalancGlobalViewController
```

Not This:

```
let viewController = GraficsBalancGlobalViewController()
```

Comment: Did I used `let viewController = GraficsBalancGlobalViewController()`? i'm new on this. And where exactly I should use this : `let viewController = storyboard.instantiateControllerWithIdentifier(identifier) as GraficsBalancGlobalViewController`? Could you explain me a little how it works?

Comment: Whatever class instantiates GraficsBalancGlobalViewController should create it that way. I assume somewhere (not mentioned above) you have a line like self.presentViewController(viewController, animated:true, completion:nil). What I said goes just above that. If it was instantiated and pushed like this: self.performSegueWithIdentifier("GraficsBalancGlobalViewControllerID", sender: nil) and you are still getting a nil its because something broke when you created the IBOutlet. In that case delete @IBOutlet weak var scrollView and drag it over from interface builder again.

Comment: I think my code is not so advanced :( , did you expected that? (i add the code above), i'm still learning how to do it.

Comment: How does the user get to GraficsBalancGlobalViewController? Is it the first screen that comes up when the app loads or do they have to get to it after pressing a button or something?

Comment: It's inside a splitView and is one of the 2 ViewControllers that manage the half of the screen, it have 2 buttons and a contentView that holds the GraficViewController. I'm going to post a new image showing that.